# combining function to display input field alongside radio button in a group of radio buttons using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have a radio **group**, which contains n number of options. Each radio button is next to a slider which I want to display only when that radio option in the group is checked.

I suppose I could identify each radio button n number of times with an id and each slider with an id to display it when checked, ex:

```
if ($('#rToggle').is(':checked')) {
        $('#pSlider1').show(); }
```

I was just wondering if there was any better way of doing it with as little IF statements as possible.

**Proposed Code (with individual ids):**

```
      <tr>
        <td class="first-column">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
          <div class="layout-slider layout-slider-radio">
            <input type="radio" id="rToggle" name="periodType" default>
          </div>
          <div class="layout-slider layout-slider-label">Day</div>
          <div id="pSlider1" class="layout-slider layout-slider-slider">
            <input id="Slider2" type="slider" name="day" value="2;15" />
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

**Actual code (without ids):**

```
      <tr>
        <td class="first-column">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
          <div class="layout-slider layout-slider-radio">
            <input type="radio" name="periodType" default>
          </div>
          <div class="layout-slider layout-slider-label">Day</div>
          <div class="layout-slider layout-slider-slider">
            <input id="Slider1" type="slider" name="day" value="2;15" />
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="first-column">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
          <div class="layout-slider layout-slider-radio">
            <input type="radio" name="periodType" default>
          </div>
          <div class="layout-slider layout-slider-label">Month</div>
          <div class="layout-slider layout-slider-slider">
            <input id="Slider2" type="slider" name="month" value="2;15" />
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="first-column">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
          <div class="layout-slider layout-slider-radio">
            <input type="radio" name="periodType" default>
          </div>
          <div class="layout-slider layout-slider-label">Year</div>
          <div class="layout-slider layout-slider-slider">
            <input id="Slider3" type="slider" name="year" value="2;15" />
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

These rows go on for n times...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options.

Put a `data-sliderid` attribute on your radio button and an ID on the `<div>` that contains the slider, for example:

HTML

```
<td>
    <div class="layout-slider layout-slider-radio">
        <input type="radio" name="periodType" data-sliderid="pSlider1" default>
    </div>
    <div class="layout-slider layout-slider-label">Day</div>
    <div id="pSlider1" class="layout-slider layout-slider-slider">
        <input id="Slider1" type="slider" name="day" value="2;15" />
    </div>
</td>
```

JavaScript

```
$('input[name="periodType"]').change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        $('#' + $(this).data('sliderid')).show();
    }
});
```

Or use DOM traversal:

```
$('input[name="periodType"]').change(function() {
    var $sliderDiv = $(this).closest('div').siblings('.layout-slider-slider');
    if(this.checked) {
        $sliderDiv.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks anthony, the Dom traversal works great. Is there anyway to hide a slider of the last selected radio group when the user selects a new one?

Comment: You could select all unchecked radio inputs with the same `name` attribute as the one that has fired the `change` event, do the same DOM traversal for each of those, and hide those elements. I'm not sure if there'd be an easier way - if **all** of your radio elements have the same `name` attribute, and **all** of the sliders on the page are connected only to those radio elements, you could simply hide all elements with `$('.layout-slider-slider').hide();`

Answer (score 0):

The is:checked function will check for the status only once. What you want is to toggle the display whenever it is unchecked/checked, so you should use the change event like this:

```
$("input[type=radio][name=foo]").change(function() {
       $("#div").toggle();
});
```